# Retrieve user profile details from mysql database when a user enters a unique code into an input box

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following code displays a BLANK PAGE when I hit the submit button. I have not a single idea what's wrong.
Help check please..

The code below:

//The html code

```
<form method="post" action="dutydata.php">
   <input type="text" placeholder="provide unique code">
   <input type="submit" name="verify">
</form>
```

//the php code

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "army_duty");
    $set = $_POST['verify'];
    if($set) {
        $show = "SELECT * FROM profile where military_number = '$set' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array(result)) {
            echo $row['military_number'];
            echo $row['first_name'];
            echo $row['last_name'];
            echo $row['paygrade'];
            echo $row['duty_status'];
            echo $row['photo'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    } else {
      echo "Military Number not found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working. Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to your queries.

Answer (score 0):

First, your input for the code needs a name:

```
<input type="text" name="code" placeholder="provide unique code">
```

This is what you will use in the query because `$_POST['verify']` does not contain any value that you would want to use.

Second, you will want to use the `$_POST['code']` number in your query:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
if($set) {
    $show = "SELECT * FROM profile where military_number = '$code' ";
```

Make sure to check for errors:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $show) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

If you want to know if something was returned from the query you test the result. Since you are only getting one record you can skip the `while()` loop:

```
if($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['military_number'];
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
    echo $row['paygrade'];
    echo $row['duty_status'];
    echo $row['photo'];
    echo "<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Military Number not found";
}
```

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Thanks Jay. It worked! Only that I noticed another little problem. When I insert a wrong code (ie one that doesn't exist in the database), it displays a blank page instead of echoing the error message I defined for it.

Comment: That's because your `else` is tied to `set`, not the result of the query.

Comment: Forgive me but that doesn't seem to be the reason. Firstly it isn't tied to set, It's outside the set braces. Although I have tweaked it around just to make sure I did what you've asked but no chance. Still didn't work please.

Comment: Still no help with that. I have checked and crosschecked

Comment: Apologies, I was away after I left the last comment. With your code indented (as edited above) the `else` is the companion to `if($set)`, so you are testing the wrong item. I'll edit my code to show you what you should be after.